# External JavaScript is not loaded when response object is loaded in new tab in Internet Explorer 11 using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a situation where I cannot use integrated JS code in my index HTML because of Content Security Policy and Cross-Site-Scripting.
So, I added my JS code as External JS files. Everything works fine in HTTP in all the browsers but in Internet Explorer 11 it fails to load the external JS references present in the response object when using HTTPS. 
I am using apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21 and has configured HTTPS in the config/server.xml file.

My index.html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button1" name="button1">OpenNewTab</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My js/test1.js code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("1st page is loaded.");
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        alert("OpenNewTab button Clicked.");
        var blankLink = "about:blank";
        var previewWindow = window.open(blankLink, '_blank');
        var response = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
        response+='<html lang="en">';
        response+='<head>';
        response+='<title>Document2</title>';
        response+='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
        response+='</head>';
        response+='<body>';
        response+='<button id="button2" name="button2">ShowAlert</button>';
        response+='<script src="js/test2.js"></script>';
        response+='</body>';
        response+='</html>';
        previewWindow.document.write(response);
    });
});
```

My js/test2.js code is

```
alert("second page is loaded.");
$("#button2").click(function(){
    alert("ShowAlert button Clicked.");
});
```

1. On page load "1st page is loaded" message is displayed.
2. On click on "openNewTab" button, "openNewTab button clicked" messag is displayed and new tab is opened with URL "about:blank".

The above 2 points works fine in all the browsers. But the following points are not working in Internet Explorer 11 in HTTPS mode. In HTTP mode, everyting works fine in all the browsers.

3. "Second page is loaded" message is displayed in second tab.
4. When clicked on "ShwoAlert" button from 2nd tab, "ShwoAlert button is clicked" message is displayed.

I tried to disable "Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls" option present in security settings for trusted sites. 
Also tried to set the security level to "low". 
Still, it is not working.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console? If it shows an error of mixed content over `HTTP` and `HTTPS` then you might find you are trying to load something over `HTTP` causing `HTTPS` to fail.

Comment: No, no such error is present in the console. Except "The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information," and "Unexpected character: U+0000 NULL. Null characters should not be used." errors.